# Expressions for LPsolve

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm working on a problem that involves constraints containing certain kind of expressions, which are to be solved using `LPsolve`. I can't seem to figure out how to formulate the constraints though.

> e.g:-  I'd like to reformulate the following constraint:

```
+0.35 C1 +0.15 C2 +0.15 C3 +0.2 C4 +0.15 C5 +0.15 C6 +0.15 C7 +0.15 C8 +0.15 C9 +0.15 C10 <= 3750;
```

as

```
+(0.35)*(1+C1) +0.15*(1+C2) +0.15*(1+C3)....+0.15*(1+C10)<= 3750;
```

I've tried using `set.constr.value()` but that only takes a fixed row  as an input.

and then solve for the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

To maximize the sum of the Ci variables subject to the constraint given int he question and assuming that they are non-negative:

```
library(lpSolve)

cc <- c(0.35, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
result <- lp(direction = "max", 
   objective = rep(1, length(cc)),
   const.mat = t(cc),
   const.dir = "<=",
   const.rhs = 3750 - sum(cc))

result
## Success: the objective function is 24988.33 

result$solution
##  [1]     0.00 24988.33     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
##  [9]     0.00     0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraint in the program (assumet `C_i >= 0`):

```
+(0.35)*(1+C1) +0.15*(1+C2) +0.15*(1+C3)....+0.15*(1+C10)<= 3750;
```

is the same as:

```
+0.35*C1 +0.15*C2 + ... +0.15*C10 <= 3750 - (0.35 + 0.15 + ... + 0.15)
```

Dont get the point of the question... Pls try to writte down the program in normal form and make your question more precise.